# when iPhone Xs,12.1 has only eSIM, How I can get mobileCountryCode?

Tags: iphone, telephony, mobile-country-code

I did not find mobile Country Code from iPhone that using only eSIM in iphone Xs,12.1 OS.

For "physical sim" following code is working fine but facing problem when installed only eSIM

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier *carrier = [netInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
NSString* mcc = [carrier mobileCountryCode];
```

Comment: can you please say did you solve tihs issue?

Comment: @Petr have u find a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

In swift, you can fetch the country code from eSIM through

```
if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
    if let countryCode = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().serviceSubscriberCellularProviders?.values.first(where: { $0.isoCountryCode != nil }) {
        print("Country Code : \(countryCode)")
    }
}
```

> Note: From iOS 12+, instead of subscriberCellularProvider, use
>   serviceSubscriberCellularProviders.

Comment: didnt work for me xcode 14.3